# Using regex to trim a specific word in String

Tags: java, regex

I am not an expert of regex. Suppose I have this string:

```
String str = "0,tcp,1.00,0.00,0.11,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,normal."
```

If I want to remove `,normal` and replace it by dot so the string becomes like this:

```
String str = "0,tcp,1.00,0.00,0.11,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00."
```

How can I do that in regex?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know what a regular expression is? Why do you want to use one?

Comment: I have a little knowledge of regular expression. If the question is not suitable, I apologize.

Comment: It's not that. It's just that you specifically want to use a regular expression but you don't know what a regex is, what kind of problem it solves and when to use one. That makes me wonder why you thought you should use one.

Comment: I am reading a file containing thousands of these records such that I want to remove the last label from every line. That's why I think regex can help here

Comment: You can do it in a lot of simpler ways. You just want to remove what's after the last comma? Just call `str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(',')) + "."`. No regular expression involved. This problem doesn't need a regular expression.

Comment: Thank you for your care .. I am SORRY I thought regular expression would help more effectively.

Comment: No need to apologize :). You should just try to read more about what regular expressions are and what problem they solve.

Comment: *I want to dig a hole. I'm not an expect with hammers, so how do I dig a hole with a hammer.* Do you see the flaw in your premise here? The answer is that a shovel would be better. Right tool for the job. Maybe your question should simply have been: *How do I dig a hole?* or *What tool should I use to dig a hole?*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression like `,\\w+\\.$` which matches any `String` ending in `,` a word and then a `.` and [`String.replaceAll(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) like

```
String str = "0,tcp,1.00,0.00,0.11,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,normal."
        .replaceAll(",\\w+\\.$", "\\.");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output is (as requested)

```
0,tcp,1.00,0.00,0.11,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. is it possible to **generalize** it to accept any word rather than `normal`?

Comment: @JeremyKemmel But did you understand what was going on? Does this solve your _real_ problem that you did not specify? Because there are a lot of simpler ways to do strictly what you want...

Comment: @JeremyKemmel Yes. Generalized the pattern to a word (`\\w+`).

Comment: why would you removed the `.` and then added it again ?